# Get JSON files from particular interval based on date field

Tags: json, bash, awk, sed, hjson

I've a lot json file the structure of which looks like below:

```
{
  key1: 'val1'
  key2: {
          'key21': 'someval1',
          'key22': 'someval2',
          'key23': 'someval3',
          'date': '2018-07-31T01:30:30Z',
          'key25': 'someval4'
  }
  key3: []
  ... some other objects
 }
```

My goal is to get only these files where date field is from some period. 
For example from 2018-05-20 to 2018-07-20.
I can't base on date of creation this files, because all of this was generated in one day. 
Maybe it is possible using sed or similar program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, the date in this format can be compared as a string. You only need something to parse the JSONs, e.g. Perl:

```
perl -l -0777 -MJSON::PP -ne '
   $date = decode_json($_)->{key2}{date};
   print $ARGV if $date gt "2018-07-01T00:00:00Z";
' *.json
```

- `-0777` makes perl slurp the whole files instead of reading them line by line
- `-l` adds a newline to `print`
- `$ARGV` contains the name of the currently processed file

See [JSON::PP](http://p3rl.org/JSON::PP) for details. If you have [JSON::XS](http://p3rl.org/JSON::XS) or [Cpanel::JSON::XS](http://p3rl.org/Cpanel::JSON::XS), you can switch to them for faster processing.

I had to fix the input (replace `'` by `"`, add commas, etc.) in order to make the parser happy.

Answer (score 1):

If your files actually contain valid JSON, the task can be accomplished in a one-liner with [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), e.g.:

```
jq 'if .key2.date[0:10] | (. >= "2018-05-20" and . <= "2018-07-31") then input_filename else empty end' *.json
```

This is just an illustration. jq has date-handling functions for dealing with more complex requirements.

### Handling quasi-JSON

If your files contain quasi-JSON, then you could use  jq in conjunction with a JSON rectifier. If your sample is representative, then [hjson](https://hjson.org/)
could be used, e.g.

```
for f in *.qjson
do
  hjson -j $f | jq --arg f "$f" '
    if .key2.date[0:7] == "2018-07" then $f else empty end'
done
```

Answer (score -2):

Try like this:

1. Find a online converter. (for example: https://codebeautify.org/json-to-excel-converter#) and convert Json to CSV
2. Open CSV file with Excel
3. Filter your data

Comment: I need to keep format of this files. I just want to get only this where key2.date is a date from some period.